# Formatar data para dd/mm/yyyy usando DatatTables .NetCore

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, jquery-datatables

Em meu projeto estou usando a biblioteca **DataTables** para montagem das minhas tabelas, o problema e que ela esta retornando a data no padrão **americano** (formato que gravo no banco de dados) e não estou conseguindo personalizar para exibir no padrão **brasileiro DD/MM/YYYY**.

Já tentei usar mascaras jQuery porém elas alteram apenas o primeiro registro, os seguintes se mantem no formato americano.
Tentei utilizar o Moment.js porém não consegui implementar. Abaixo meus códigos e um print da tabela.

**JS personalizado da DataTables**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#table").dataTable({

    aLengthMenu: [
      [5, 10, 25, -1],
      [5, 10, 25, "Todos"],
    ],
    iDisplayLength: 5,

   "language": {
        "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
    }
  });
});
```

Tabela:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="display-5">
            <i class="fas fa-ticket-alt fa-lg"></i>
            Tickets Abertos
            <a asp-action="NovoTicket" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Novo Ticket">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>
            </a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-md">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Equipamento</th>
                <th>PA</th>
                <th>Problema</th>
                <th>Data Abertura</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Responsável</th>
                <th>Opções</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketId)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Equipamento.TipoDeEquipamento)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PA.Nome)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)</td>
                    <td">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataAbertura)</td>
                    <td>R$ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valor)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Usuario.Nome)</td>

                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="AtualizarTicket" asp-route-TicketId="@item.TicketId" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Atualizar Ticket">
                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi adicionando uma DataAnnotations formatando a data no Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DataAbertura { get; set; }

DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DataEncerramento { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar uma cultura padrão na inicialização da sua aplicação.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Define a cultura padrão como "pt-BR"
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
}
```

Ou então você pode forçar o formato no razor caso sua variável **DataAbertura** seja do tipo **DateTime**.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataAbertura.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))
```

Comment: Usando a cultura da certo, porem no meu projeto em especifico preciso da cultura em inglês. Já tentando usar o ToString na View recebi o seguinte erro: "InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."